# Set MySQL timestamp to random time within past 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a timestamp column in my MySQL table.

I'm wanting to set this timestamp to a random time within the past 24 hours for all rows in the table.

I know I can update all the rows doing this:

```
UPDATE table SET timestamp =
```

But I can't find if there's a way to set a random timestamp that's occurred within the past 24 hours so that each row has a different time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
UPDATE table
    SET timestamp = now() - interval floor((24*60*60)*rand()) second;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unixtimestqamps for that

```
UPDATE table1
    SET timestamp = (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 
          FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, NOW()))
          , NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Update table set timestamp = select(cast((sysdate() - floor(rand()*24)) AS Datetime));
```